# How to evaluate $\sum_{n=1}^m 2^n \arctan 2^n \theta$

Tags: summation

I need to evaluate $$\sum_{n=1}^m 2^n \arctan 2^n \theta$$ as a function of $m$ and $\theta$. All I've done so far is write out the series explicitly:

$$\sum_{n=1}^m 2^n \arctan 2^n \theta = 2 \arctan 2\theta + 4\arctan 4\theta + 8\arctan 8\theta + \cdots + 2^m \arctan 2^m \theta$$

and I initially considered pairing every two terms up to use the $\arctan x + \arctan y$ trick, but it doesn't work because each $\arctan$ term has a different coefficient.

Comment: you could tr the trick with splitting up the summation into multiple summations, if only the coefficients were the problem.

Comment: $f_{m}(\theta)=2f_{m-1}(2\theta) + 2\arctan 2\theta$. Not sure whether that helps.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews, am I misunderstanding? 

$2^m \arctan 2^m \theta = 2 \cdot 2^{m-1} \arctan (2^{m-1} \cdot 2\theta) + 2\arctan 2\theta$, surely that's not correct?

Comment: I was implicitly defining $f_m(\theta)$ as your sum, not as  $2^m\arctan(2^m\theta)$. @ZainPatel

Comment: @ThomasAndrews, ah - my bad. I shall work with that and see if anything comes to light. :-)

Comment: It's a very strange variable choice that the argument to $\arctan$ is some integer multiple of $\theta$. The argument to $\arctan$ is unit-less, while $\theta$ is usually an angle. It's just weird to use them together. Not wrong, per se, but might indicate an error, if this question comes in the middle of some other work.

Comment: It's just a pure summation question, where the argument is used because of the trigonometrical setting. At least, I'd hope so...

Comment: @ZainPatel But the input to $\arctan$ is a real number, not an angle. It is the *output* of it which is an angle.

Answer (score 6):

Not for nothing, but just in case the OP really wants to evaluate

$$\sum_{n=1}^m 2^n \tan{2^n \theta} $$

then use the fact that

$$\cot{x}-2 \cot{2 x} = \tan{x} $$

and let $x=2^n \theta$. In this case, we get a telescoping sum with the result

$$\sum_{n=1}^m 2^n \tan{2^n \theta} = 2\cot{2 x} - 2^{m+1} \cot{2^{m+1} \theta}$$

Comment: This makes it almost seem OP really meant tan rather than arctan. (+1)

Comment: @coffeemath: it's odd to have arctan of an angle...